# What is a good open source load balancer?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server

I want to balance load between two web servers. Other than Varnish which seems to be primarily a reverse proxy, what other choices do I have?

Comment: Kyriakos, welcome to Server Fault!  However, you should be aware that product recommendation questions are explicitly off-topic as per our FAQ (which is linked from the top of every page, and which in turn links to an explanation of this policy).  If this question gets closed soon, please don't take it to heart; we look forward to your questions in future (after you've read the FAQ ;-).

Answer (score 2):

In one word `HAproxy`. featureful, good documentation and has proved to run stable in prod environments.

`Pound` is also a good alternative but I would still go for HAproxy

Answer (score -1):

`HAProxy`, `NginX`, `squid` - all could loadbalance.